# xcode 6 swift Slow typing & Autocompletion

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode6

i suffer with typing & Autocompletion it takes too much time, this issue occurs only when the swift file has more than 1500+ Line code. with small lines codes for example under 1000 Line everything will be Fine.

so I've tried to split the swift View controller file into 2 swift files,

I've taken the longer functions from the view Controller and paste them into the new swift file, xcode 6 works just as expected.

But a new problem arises which swift doesn't support importing swift file Into another Swift File. so i've created an instance of the view controller in the newly created swift file, so i thought i saved the problem, but the instance of the view controller can only access Variables, Constants,And Functions,

check the error

viewController.swift

```
viewController: UIViewController
{
  var someClass = foo() // assuming this class has x = 5
  var x: Int = 10
}
```

testFile.swift

```
 import Foundation
 let beginTest = viewController()
  func testPrint()
  {
    println("x in view Controller = \(beginTest.x)") // prints 10 
    println("x in the foo() = \(beginTest.someClass.x)") // Error view controller doesn't have a member named someClass

  }
```

How can i solve this problem, without creating instances or importing files.

or

How can i solve this problem, with Creating instances of view Controller ?

P.s. I have Macbook Air mid 2013, core i5, 4Gb, Intel HD Graphics 5000 1536MB

Comment: Why do you have 1500-line source code files?  You shouldn't have this... this is your problem, not autocomplete failing...

Comment: Well, other user complains because the xcode suffer when it gets to 8000+ line source code, so 1500 are nothing compared to a video game source code :)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with 1500 or 8000 lines of source code.  The problem is when all of this source code are in the same file for absolutely no reason.  You *might* be able to find a game with 8000 lines of source code in a single file, but you won't find any code authored by anyone that knows what they're doing that is anywhere near this many lines of source code.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using 'extension' s in swift to logically split your implementation of a class as required.  [Refer documentaion](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html)

For example, we can split implementation of a class A thusly in two files:

```
//A.Swift 

class A
{
    func func1() -> String {
        return "func1"
    }
//Other functions...


}

//A_Extension.swift

extension  A
{
    func funcB() -> String
    {
        return "B"
    }
 //Other functions if any...


}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have test coverage data gathering enabled (edit scheme, test) disable it. For me this speeds up editing by order of magnitude.